# How do I make sure an input SQL Statement has valid column names using Java?

Tags: java, sql, validation

I am writing Java program that reads in SQL Statement as string file, however the programs needs to validate that the SQL statement has valid column names. There are 2 files that hold the column names and they are stored in a string as well.  I am struggling with figuring out the logic on how to compare both files to the one SQL statement string.

Here is an example of a possible SQL Statement the user can input:
SELECT * JobHost where class_id ='MAA';

My first approach is to split the file by select & from then read it line by line and store it an array list. And then compare the array list to the string file column names or maybe place the column names in an array list.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: If you've got an SQL statement that contains column names, then you're going to have to parse the SQL statement to identify the column names.  But I don't understand why you want to do it this way.  What SQL statements do you intend to process?  How complicated can they be?

Comment: If you are concerned about column names, I do recommend you to use column names, instead of `*`. Can you show an example about what you are doing to be easier for us to help?

Comment: `I am writing Java program that reads in SQL Statement as string file` ... What does that mean? Are you reading CSV files? `Here is an example of a possible SQL Statement the user can input: SELECT * JobHost where class_id ='MAA';` ... Don't allow the User to enter arbitrary table field names. Force the User to select those table field names from a list like from a drop-down combo-box. This way there is nothing to confirm. You can easily get the table meta-data in order to acquire table field names.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible.

SQL is a complex language and the only way to do what you want is to write a full blown SQL parser which is a project that involves being quite familiar with very complicated libraries (parser libraries). An expert would need weeks to build that up.

Your question also makes assumptions you can't make. These are examples of valid SQL, and they don't select on columns, but columns are involved in some of these:

- `SELECT 1;`
- `SELECT colname > 1 FROM foo;`
- `SELECT x."ALIAS" FROM (SELECT colname AS alias FROM table) x;`
- `SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from colname) FROM table;`

Just look at that third one, and realize that you stand no chance.

Then look at the 4th and realize that *if* you want to go down the path of validating that some string contains sane SQL prior to throwing that SQL at the database is vastly more complex than you seem to think it is: That `colname` can still be checked, but you shouldn't stop at checking if that is a valid column, you should also check if the column is of a type that is supported in an `EXTRACT(YEAR from)` operation.

Then realize that just about every SQL engine out there supports widely different SQL syntax and extensions, so you can't just write one SQL parser, you'd have to write one for psql, one for mysql, one for mssql, and so on.

Hopeless situation.

### So, what to do?

Just run that stuff: Toss it at the DB. If it's invalid, the DB will tell you with an `SQLException`. you can fetch the specific db error from this with `sqlEx.getSQLState()`. Unfortunately, that string is entirely dependent on the underlying SQL engine, but fortunately, most SQL engines give highly specific machine parsable information. For example, if there's gobbledygook in there, psql would give you `42601`. If you want to tell the difference, write an SQL statement with a specific problem you'd like to know about (such as using a colname that doesn't exist), run it, print the SQLState. Now you know what to look for.